# CSS Wrapper background color

Tags: html, css, layout

I'm making a website that has multiple wrappers with a width of 100% and a div inside it containing content. On one of the wrappers no bg colour appears but it works with no issues on a wrapper further down the page. Can anyone spot the issue or assist? Thanks

```
#wrappergrey {
width: 100%;
background-color:#e8e8e8;
margin: 0 auto;
}

#reviews {
width:1200px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
background:#e8e8e8;
padding:10px;
font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
text-align: center;
}

<div id="wrappergrey">

<div id="reviews">

<div id="five-stars">
<img src="images/5stars.png"><br>
<strong>TIME MAGAZINE</strong><br>
A wildly original roller-coaster ride of hilarious mischief.
</div>

<div id="five-stars">
<img src="images/5stars.png"><br>
<strong>CHICAGO TRIBUNE</strong><br>
A horror-comedy about cute little Christmas toy/pets who turn into murderous       monsters wreaking havoc on a Norman Rockwellian town.
</div>
```

What I see:

[image]

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: It should also be noted that you are using the same ID more than once on a page...which is incorrect.